# Operator overloading and different template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, ambiguity

I have a problem overloading the operator+ i a templated class.
Suppose I have

```
template<typename T>
struct point{

    //Ctors:
    point(){};
    point(T _x, T _y):x(_x),y(_y){};
    point(const point<T>& p):x(p.x),y(p.y){};

    template<typename T2>
    point(const point<T2>& p):x(static_cast<T>(p.x)),y(static_cast<T>(p.y)){};



   //Coordinates:
   T x;
   T y;


   //Operator overloads:
   friend point<T> operator+(point<T> left,point<T> right ){
       return point<T>(left.x+right.x, left.y+right.y);
   }

   template<class T2>
   friend point<T> operator+(point<T2> left,point<T> right){
       return point<T>(left)+right;

   }

   template<class T3>
   friend point<T> operator+(point<T> left,point<T3> right){
       return point<T>(right)+left;
   }


};
```

This gives me an ambiguity error when calling.

```
point<float> p1(1.2,1.4);
point<int> p2(1,2);    
point<float> p3 =p1+p2;
```

This makes sense, but can you tell me good practice on how to fix it?

I need 3 operators, since otherwise the casting might go in the wrong direction. For example disregarding the last operator overload would result in `p3.x=2` and `p3.y=4`.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you need 3 operator +s?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know which function select (T2 or T3).
The difference must be in parameters (not in return type).

Comment: @AdamFolwarczny I understand that this is ambiguous, but could you tell me how to fix it. I couldn't really find a nice solution for which to casting basically depends on the return type.

Comment: expression templates?

Comment: If float has always higher priority then return result as float.
If will you assing it to point<int> then it will convert automaticly:
   
   `template<class T, class T2>`
   `point<float> operator+(point<T2> left, point<T> right){`
   `return point<float>(left) + point<float>(right);`
   `}`

Comment: @AdamFolwarczny It doesn't always have a higher priority. I mean it should just cast to the type I'm assigning it to.

Comment: It's pointless to overload such combination. If you want to overload  for different types, just keep one of the last two. The key is you must pick the widest side to convert to.

Comment: There is a pattern in the code to try to allow for as many types and conversions as possible. That is often a bad idea. Even if you fix the operator+ issue, two points of different types are implicitly convertible to each other. Restricting the usage is not always a bad idea, and it might actually improve the usage by avoiding all these pitfalls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To some degree this is a matter of personal preference and subjective opinion, but I think I would try to emulate the ordinary C++ rules for result types of arithmetic expressions, e.g.

```
template <class T1, class T2 >
friend
auto operator+( Point<T1> const left, Point<T2> const right )
    -> Point< decltype( left.x + right.x ) > 
{
    return {left.x + right.x, left.y + right.y};
}
```

---

Satisfying both g++ 4.8.2 and visual c++ 12.0 turned out to be more complicated than I imagined, but here's concrete code that compiles cleanly with both those compilers:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template< class Number >
struct Point
{
    Number  x;
    Number  y;
};

template< class T1, class T2 >
auto operator+( Point<T1> const left, Point<T2> const right )
    -> Point< typename std::remove_const<decltype( left.x + right.x )>::type > 
{
    using Result_number =
        typename std::remove_const<decltype( left.x + right.x )>::type;
    using Result_point = Point< Result_number >;
    return Result_point{ left.x + right.x, left.y + right.y };
}

auto main()
    -> int
{
    Point<float> const  p1{ 1.2, 1.4 };
    Point<int> const    p2{ 1, 2 };
    Point<float> const  p3 = p1 + p2;
}
```

---

In order to facilitate possible narrowing conversions of `Point` you can add an explicit conversion operator member function, like this:

```
template< class Number >
struct Point
{
    Number  x;
    Number  y;

    template< class Other_number >
    explicit
    operator Point<Other_number>() const
    {
        return Point<Other_number>{
            static_cast<Other_number>( x ),
            static_cast<Other_number>( y )
            };
    }
};
```

To invoke use any suitable cast, e.g. apparent constructor notation (which with the above definitions is just a cast that invokes the conversion operator):

```
    Point<int> const    p4 = Point<int>( p1 + p2 );
```

Comment: +1, even if probably more complicated than what the user really needs... Also, are you missing references in the operator arguments?

Comment: I wasn't sure about using reference arguments. With 64-bit programming I think the efficiency maybe is better for pass by value. But I don't know.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks a lot! That's nice code! One more stupid follow up though. What's the difference in using the copy constructor in my code as `template<typename T2> point(const point<T2>& p):x(static_cast<T>(p.x)),y(static_cast<T>(p.y)){};` and a your conversion function?

Comment: @user3428018: As sketched above the `Point` class is *trivially copyable*, since it has no "non-trivial copy constructors" (C++11 §9/6). Among other things, the template argument of `atomic<T>` is required to be trivially copyable. The main idea is that the class' value notion derives only from the bitpattern so that copying the bits yields the same logical value, this notion embodied in  §3.9/3. I don't think this is very important at all, *but* it comes for free just by being a little careful. E.g. not introducing constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have result in type of the result parameter then create method to compute it:

```
   template<class T, class T2, class T3>
   void AddPoints(const point<T>& a, const point<T2>& b, point<T3>& result)
   {
       result = point<T3>(a) + point<T3>(b);
   }

int main()
{
    point<float> p1(1.2,1.4);
    point<int> p2(1,2);    
    point<double> result; 
    AddPoints(p1, p2, result);
}
```

Comment: Of course this is always possible, but an operator overload seems much cleaner and nicer! Is there a way to do it with an operator-overload?